# libusb communicate with USB mass storage

Tags: java, c++, c, usb, libusb

I'm currently writing a [javax-usb (JSR-80)](http://javax-usb.org/) implementation using [libusb 0.1](http://www.libusb.org/) as a backend. I need to test the bulk transfer functionality and my guess is that the easiest way to do this is to communicate with a USB mass storage device like a USB flash drive. Unfortunately I have no idea how these devices are working. I guess there is some kind of protocol and I have to send some USB control requests before I can initiate a transfer on the bulk endpoints.

I'm not interested in writing a full USB mass storage driver or something like that so even file system stuff doesn't matter. My only purpose is to transfer some data via some bulk endpoint so I can compare my implementation with the reference implementation.

What I need is some example code (Language doesn't matter and most likely it even doesn't matter if it uses libusb or something different) or a specification of USB mass storage which is easy to understand for programmers (I'm no hardware specialist). I already searched the web but haven't found anything useful so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [USB device class specifications](https://www.usb.org/documents?search=&type[]=55) are really not all that difficult to read assuming you know the basics of USB (since you're writing a USB driver, I assume you do). [Mass Storage Bulk Only v1.0](https://www.usb.org/sites/default/files/usbmassbulk_10.pdf) is probably the document you want.

Comment: Link to USB device lass specification broken:
 http://www.usb.org/developers/docs/devclass_docs/